# Insert shape in kendo gridcell

Tags: kendo-grid

I am trying to replicate a user's excel sheet data in kendo grid.

In some columns, shapes are inserted

[image]

How can I insert/draw a shape in a kendo grid cell? I am new to this, and at the moment only know how to specify a data source and then push it.

Any ideas and suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I researched how to input html in a kendo grid cell. That led me to the property encoded. I set it to false for the columns in which I wanted to generate my custom html i.e. a circle

```
                {
                    title: "Event Capture",
                    field: "eventCapture",
                    encoded:false,
                    type: "string"
                },
```

Then when I pushed the data, I pushed the complete desired html.

And this is the result I got:

[image]

Which is pretty much what I wanted. I hope this helps someone